# Xna Glowing 3D shape as in Geometry Wars

Tags: xna, lines, monogame, wireframe

This is probably a strange question, but I want to know. And this is assuming they did not use 2D sprite sheets. From my understanding of Geometry Wars, the enemy shapes were created with 3D shapes, and the wireframe of the shapes were shown, and glowed. I already know how the glowing works (the Bloom effect, which I have working right now, and creates the correct effect). How do I make these wireframe-like models in Xna? Do I need to create a model and show wireframes? (I have no idea how to do that). If Geometry Wars does not use these wireframe 3D shapes, another example is PewPew. In PewPew, the graphics look and feel almost the same as Geometry Wars. However, PewPew sometimes changes the camera angle. In this different angle, the shapes are 3D, and no longer 2D. Again, my question is how can I make this effect in Xna (MonoGame, to be exact)?

Answer (score 0):

To enable wireframe, make and render models normally, but at the end of LoadContent, use this: (You can also place this in the Draw method if your settings change around at runtime too much, but it's not recommended)

```
 RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
 rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
 GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;
```

Also, you can simply place a camera straight above the world-plane for a simple 3D/2D combo, and/or use `Matrix.CreateOrthographic`, which will give the world a flat 2D appearance.

Comment: In wireframe mode, can I change the color of the lines?

Comment: Would I create a shader effect to change colors? I think that is how. I do not have very much 3D experience (I'm a 2D person), and would like to learn more.